# set modalities as new columns

Tags: python, pandas

From this kind of data::

```
d = { 'Media': {0: 'M1', 1: 'M2', 2: 'M7', 3: 'M1', 4: 'M2', 5: 'M1'},
         'pi': {0: 'p84', 1: 'p84', 2: 'p84', 3: 'p84', 4: 'p73', 5: 'p73'},
         'qj': {0: 'q82', 1: 'q4', 2: 'q5', 3: 'q2', 4: 'q23', 5: 'q9'},
     'Budget': {0: 39, 1: 15, 2: 13, 3: 53, 4: 82, 5: 70} }
dd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
dd
#    Budget Media   pi   qj
# 0      39    M1  p84  q82
# 1      15    M2  p84   q4
# 2      13    M7  p84   q5
# 3      53    M1  p84   q2
# 4      82    M2  p73  q23
# 5      70    M1  p73   q9
```

I need to create *res* a new dataframe such as for each Media modality Budget has a column e.g.:

```
res
#    Media   pi   qj Budget MediaM1 MediaM2 MediaM7
# 0     M1  p84  q82     39      39       0       0
# 1     M2  p84   q4     15       0      15       0
# 2     M7  p84   q5     13       0       0      13
# 3     M1  p84   q2     53      53       0       0
# 4     M2  p73  q23     82       0      82       0
# 5     M1  p73   q9     70      70       0       0
```

Comment: How do you propose to do that?

Comment: a starting point might be `pd.crosstab(dd.Budget,dd.Media)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's on way to do it.

Get the crosstab on `dd['Budget'], dd['Media']`

```
In [21]: cross = pd.crosstab(dd['Budget'], dd['Media'], values=dd['Budget'], aggfunc=sum)

In [22]: cross
Out[22]:
Media   M1  M2  M7
Budget
13     NaN NaN  13
15     NaN  15 NaN
39      39 NaN NaN
53      53 NaN NaN
70      70 NaN NaN
82     NaN  82 NaN
```

And, then merge on `dd` and fill `NaN's` with `0`

```
In [23]: dd.merge(cross.reset_index()).fillna(0)
Out[23]:
   Budget Media   pi   qj  M1  M2  M7
0      39    M1  p84  q82  39   0   0
1      15    M2  p84   q4   0  15   0
2      13    M7  p84   q5   0   0  13
3      53    M1  p84   q2  53   0   0
4      82    M2  p73  q23   0  82   0
5      70    M1  p73   q9  70   0   0
```